# Linux - How to list all users and their UIDs

Tags: linux, awk, grep, uid

How to write a script for linux which list all users from /etc/passwd and their UID

```
User1 uid=0001
User2 uid=0002
...
```

the script should use: grep, cut, id, for

Comment: This really isn't a homework platform.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
awk -F: '$0=$1 " uid="$3' /etc/passwd
```

awk is easier in this case.

-F defines field separator as `:`

so you want is 1st and 3rd colums.  so build the `$0` to provide your output format.

this is very basic usage of powerful awk. you may want to read some tutorials if you faced this kind of problem often.

This time you got fish, if I were you, I am gonna do some research on how to fishing.

Answer (score 9):

`cut` is nice for this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

This means "cut, using `:` as the delimeter, everything except the first field from each line of the `/etc/passwd` file".

Answer (score 4):

I think best option is as that:
**`grep "/bin/bash" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1`**

Comment: this answer is what I am looking for. It gives users that can login using GUI :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  -F':' '$3>999 {print $1 " uid: " $3}' /etc/passwd | column -t | grep -v nobody
```

Gives you all regular users (uid >= 1000) neatly ordered including the userid.